# How to apply transition animation to the .go function using the go_router package

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I am using the go_router package because I need the deep linking it provides. I applied animation transitions to some routes but they are static, so every time I go to that route, the same animation is going to trigger. I would like to change the animation when I do `GoRouter.of(context).go('/inbox')`

This is what I have right now:

```
final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/inbox',
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/inbox',
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return PageTransition.slideFromRight(
          myChildWidget: Layout(
            context: context,
            state: state,
            child: EmailPage(),
          ),
          state: state,
        );
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/email/inbox/:id',
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return PageTransition.slideFromLeft(
          myChildWidget: Layout(
            context: context,
            state: state,
            child: const EmailDetailsPage(),
          ),
          state: state,
        );
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/menu',
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return PageTransition.slideFromRight(
          myChildWidget: Layout(
            context: context,
            state: state,
            child: const MenuPage(),
          ),
          state: state,
        );
      },
    )
  ],
);
```

PageTransition is just a custom transition Widget I build.

So, in this case, if I do `GoRouter.of(context).go('/inbox')` it will play the `slideFromRight` transition, if I do `GoRouter.of(context).go('/email/inbox/:id')` it will play the `slideFromLeft` and I can't change that. I would like for this to be dynamic and choose what animation it is going to play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [go_router](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Transition%20animations-topic.html) provides `CustomTransitionPage` for transition animations.

##### Code:

```
GoRoute(
  path: 'details',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    return CustomTransitionPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      child: DetailsScreen(),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        // Change the opacity of the screen using a Curve based on the the animation's
        // value
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity:
              CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

##### Reference: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/transition_animations.dart